# php riddle - interesting result

Tags: php, logic

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$cups = array();
for($i=0; $i<500; $i++){
    $cups[$i] = 0;
}

for($x=1; $x<500; $x++){
    for($y=$x; $y<500; $y+=$x){
        $cups[$y] = !$cups[$y];
    }
}

foreach($cups as $key => $value){
    if($value == 1){
        echo "{$key}, ";
    }
}

?>
```

As you can see, I fill up an array with 500 zeroes, loop through it twice, and then print out the cup numbers that have a '1' in them:

```
1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484,
```

As you can see - it outputs squares.
I think the phenomenon is impressive, but I am interested in a mathematical explanation -

Why does this pattern occur?

Thanks!

Comment: whoever marked this as "not a real question" - my question is why does this pattern occur?

Comment: ‘Not programming related’ would be more appropriate. It's simple maths: natural numbers have pairs of factors, except for square numbers, where one of the factors occurs twice, but is only counted once by your loop.

Comment: I +1 this one because it's an interesting problem when translated into software, which makes it programming related.

Comment: You having a go at me or what? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works this way because this is the classic [Locker Problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235818/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54242.html)... and in the locker problem, only the numbers with odd number of factors are returned... which are all the squares.

Answer (score 4):

Well you are flipping the state once for each unique factor.

Squares have an odd number of unique factors.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If you decompose each number in unique factors, all the factors occurs by 2 and they are different... except for the square numbers.

Example 1 : 20 = (1*20) or (2*10) or (5*4).  
Example 2 : 16 = (1*16) or (2*8) or (4*4) <- these two are the same, so your loop only pass 1 time there, so the final result will be 1 for this key.

Answer (score 2):

I put sort of a play by play in the comments:

```
<?php

$cups = array();
for($i=0; $i<500; $i++){
    $cups[$i] = 0;
}
// fill up indices 1-500

// at this step you set up the loop, and increment x
for($x=1; $x<500; $x++){
// since $x is now 2, you are actually looping from 2 to 500, and
// adding 2 to every iteration of $y
    for($y=$x; $y<500; $y+=$x){
 // now you're only showing a value if theyre not the same
    $cups[$y] = !$cups[$y];
    }
}

foreach($cups as $key => $value){
    // here you only loop through those with a value (which is every value + 2) 
    // you are basically counting by 2s (2, 4, 
    if($value == 1){
        echo "{$key}, ";
    }


}
```

Basically what you are creating is a list of numbers with odd factors, which are squares.

Notice how each value is incremented in a sequence of value + 2:

```
1  + 3 = 4
4  + 5 = 9
9  + 7 = 16
16 + 9 = 25
```

and so on.

I'm sure someone will explain it much more accurately and succinct than I did, but this gives you some idea of what's going on here.